# Is there a package to draw model of measure system?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is the picture I'd like to draw.

[image]

I have used *draw node* in *tikzpicture*
but it's super complicated.

Comment: See section 4.14 (page 88) of the circuitikz manual.  It will still be complicated.

Comment: @JohnKormylo 
https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikzmanual.pdf/0

Comment: @JohnKormylo Which manual are you referring to? Could you please provide a link?

Comment: Every package comes with a manual, usually PDF.  See also https://ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz?lang=en.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schemabloc package (https://ctan.org/pkg/schemabloc) allows you to create block diagrams.
The proposed scheme is not "easily" achievable but it is possible.
here

```
\documentclass[11pt, A4]{article}

\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                 % Titres en fran�ais
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % Correspondance clavier -> document
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} 


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{schemabloc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\sbEntree{I}                    
    \node[left]at(I){$I$}  ;
    \node[below right]at(I){$Input$};
\sbBloc[5]{K}{$K$}{I}   \sbRelier{I}{K}
\sbDecaleNoeudy[4]{I}{N}
\sbDecaleNoeudy[-4]{I}{Mult}
\sbDecaleNoeudy[-8]{I}{Km}
\sbBloc[5]{Mult}{$ \times $}{Mult}  \sbRelieryx{I-K-2}{Mult}
\sbBloc[5]{N}{$N()$}{N}        \sbRelieryx{I-K-2}{N}
\sbBloc[5]{Km}{$K_M$}{Km}
    \sbRelier{Km}{Mult}
\sbCompSum*[7]{sum1}{K}{+}{+}{+}{ }
\sbRelier[$KI$]{K}{sum1}  
\sbRelierxy[$K_MI_MI$]{Mult}{sum1}
\sbRelierxy[$N(I)$]{N}{sum1}

\sbCompSum*[6]{sum2}{sum1}{+}{+}{+}{ }

\sbDecaleNoeudy[-6]{sum1}{Ki}
\sbBloc[4.5]{Ki}{$K_I$}{Ki}
\sbRelier{Ki}{sum2}
\sbRelier{sum1}{sum2}
\sbSortie[6]{O}{sum2}               \sbRelier{sum2}{O}   
    \node[right]at(O){$O$};
    \node[below left]at (O){$Output$} ;
    
\draw[latex-] (sum2) -- node[left]{$a$}  ++(0,-2);
\draw[latex-] (Ki) --  ++(0,2.5)node[left]{$I_1$} ;
\draw[latex-] (Km) --  ++(0,1.5) node[right]{$I_M$};

\node[fit=(Km) (Ki) (N) (sum2),draw,dashed,inner sep=0.5cm]{};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]